# Camel JMS ensuring ordering when unsidelining from dead letter channel

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using camel to integrate with ActiveMQ JMS. I am receiving prices for products on this queue. I am using JMSXGroupID on productId to ensure ordering across a productId. Now if I fail to process this message I move it to a DeadLetterQueue. This could be because of a connection error on a dependent service or because of error with the message itself.
In case of the former I would have to manually remove it from the DLQ and put it back into the JMS queue.
Now the problem is that I dont know if any other message on that groupId has been received and processed or not. And hence unsidelining from DLQ will disrupt the order. On the other hand if I dont unsideline it and no other message has been received the product Id will not get the correct price.
1 solution that I have in mind is to use a fast key-value store(Redis) to store the last messageId or JMSTimestamp against a productId(message group). This is updated everytime I dequeue a message. Any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Relying on message order in JMS is a risky business - at best.
The best thing to do is to make the receiver handle messages out of sequence as a special case (but may take advantage message order during normal operation).

You may also want to distinguish between two errors: posion messages and temporary connection problems, maybe even use two different error queues for them. In the case of a posion message (invalid payload etc.) then there is nothing you can really do about it except starting a bug investigation. In such cases, you can probably send along "something else", such as dummy message to not interfere with order.

For the issues with connection problems, you can have another strategy - ActiveMQ Redelivery Policies. If there is network trouble, it's usually no use in trying to process the second message until the first has been handled. A Redelivery Policy ensures that (given you have a single consumer, that is). There is [another question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736292/how-is-ordering-preserved-in-activemq) where the poster actually has a solution to your problem and wants to avoid it. Read it. :)